# graph-cli installs but is not getting read

Tags: bash, blockchain, subgraph, thegraph

I am installing `@graphprotocol/graph-cli` with `yarn` with the command

```
yarn global add @graphprotocol/graph-cli
```

I get the success message saying:

```
success Installed "@graphprotocol/graph-cli@0.31.0" with binaries:
  - graph
```

But when I try to check its version with `graph --version` it says:

```
Command 'graph' not found, but can be installed with:
sudo apt install plotutils
```

I don't know how to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 1):

So ubuntu was not picking it up from the installed directory. What fixed it for me was this command:

```
yarn global add @graphprotocol/graph-cli --prefix /usr/local
```

I had to specify where yarn should install this package. After running this command it automatically picked graph in the terminal. If anyone can explain why this worked, I'd be obliged.

Comment: Try also this solution but seems like it does not work for Ubuntu 20

Answer (score 0):

I went through the same error and fix it by using npm

> `npm install -g @graphprotocol/graph-cli`